# Ionic 5 Cordova Geolocation and Geocoder sometimes cant get latitude and longitude

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic5

I am using cordova geolocation plugin to get coordinates and address but some times its not get user coordinates

```
options = {
    timeout: 20000, 
    enableHighAccuracy: true, 
    maximumAge: 3600
  };

  getCurrentCoordinates() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.options).then((resp) => {
      this.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
      
      
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error getting coordinates', error);
     });
  }
```

Comment: Happens on all devices? Do you get an error?

Comment: @1x2x3x4x yes its happens sometimes on all device.. and display error like "error getting cordova location"

Comment: I'm using that plugin and I have no problems. But I only call it once. Are you doing background checks? Also, try opening an issue https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Comment: @1x2x3x4x I am using on  ngOnInit event.. Its use multiple time. Please share your code

Comment: I use this exact code: https://enappd.com/blog/using-geolocation-geocoding-and-reverse-geocoding-in-ionic-4/45/ make sure your device is ready.

Comment: @1x2x3x4x ngOnInit(){
    
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.getCurrentCoordinates();
  });
  }